# Evaluate a finite sum with combinations.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

I am computing the number of minors for a matrix $A_{m\times n}$. It is known that the number of $k$-minors of the matrix $A$ is $${m\choose k}\times {n\choose k}.$$ Therefore the total number of minors is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)}{m\choose k}\times {n\choose k}.$$ 
Now if $m\geq n$, then $\min(m,n)=n$. In this case, how should I go about evaluating this series? Any hints/ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be seen as a special case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity):
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\min(m,n)}{m\choose k}\times {n\choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{m\choose k}\times {n\choose n-k}-1={m+n\choose n}=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}-1.$$